# How to restore a coding environment?

Tags: ansi-term, term

Every other day I continue work on a coding project which involves these steps:

1. Open a file in the project
2. Open a terminal buffer e.g.: `m-x` `term`
3. Change to that term buffer
4. Enter command in termin e.g. : `pytest myfile.py`
5. Enter another terminal buffer e.g.: `m-x` `ansi-term`
6. Change to that term buffer
7. Enter command in ansi-termin e.g. : `journalctl -f`
8. Arrange all buffers
9. Resize all buffers

Do I have to live with that or can this be done by a function/keypress?

Note: In particular the **restore of terminal commands is crucial**. Google *restore terminal in emacs* suggests answers on restoring buffers

Comment: Use a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros)?